# Not able to access my web application directly through browser when I start tomcat using startup.bat

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat8

I have configured tomcat 8.0.23 in eclipse IDE.

I have developed jsp-servlet web application using eclipse IDE. I can run my application from eclipse [Run As -> Run on server] without any problem.

Now, I want to access my application directly through browser [without eclipse] i.e starting tomcat using startup.bat . When start tomcat using startup.bat, tomcat starts perfectly.

But when I try to access my application directly through browser using url [http://localhost:8080/MyProject/index.jsp] it shows message:- "404 The requested resource is not available".

What configuration I need to do in tomcat, in order to access my web application through browser? Should I keep my project inside webapps too?

Comment: OK BalusC...thanks for the help..I'll go through the link which u hv given...

Comment: yes... got the solution on that link...thanks